# Hping showing -400% packet loss

Tags: linux, ping

I used the following command:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/hping3 -q -n -c 5 -S <hostname> -p 8080
```

and the output I got is:

```
1 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, -400% packet loss
```

Can you please explain why only 1 packet was sent when "-c 5" is set and how did it receive 5 packets. and also what does -400% packet loss mean?

Comment: This seems like a bug in the output to me. I guess it sent out 5 packets and received 5 packets. The `-400% packet loss` is just a follow-up error because sending out 1 packet and receiving 5 arithmetically results in a negative packet loss (= a packet 'gain'). Can you reproduce this behaviour or did it only happen one time?

Comment: This is happening every time I try the port number 8080. My tomcat application is listening on port 8080 in the remote server

Answer (score 1):

> why only 1 packet was sent when "-c 5" is set

Did you [read the man page](http://www.hping.org/manpage.html)? That's exactly what it's supposed to do.

> how did it receive 5 packets

We don't know - if you run tcpdump or wireshark then the reason might be a bit clearer. If it took a long time to return, then most likely the remote host is resending the syn-ack packet.

> what does -400% packet loss mean?

```
100 * (packets sent - packets received) / packets sent
= 100*(1-5)/1
= -400
```

Comment: I think you accidentally the minus sign on the last line.

Comment: Indeed - amended.